CSS para pantalla dark-mode funciona en iOS pero no funciona en Android en Emails
Estoy realizando pruebas para campañas de emailing para implementar mediante CSS los cambios necesarios para que el usuario que cambie la configuración de su pantalla o dispositivo a dark-mode puedan adecuarse a diseño y accesibilidad. Para ello he estado buscando documentación sobre como implementar este css y utilizando las @media (preferes-color-scheme) reconoce y aplica los cambios para los dispositivos iOS, pero en Android no reconoce cambios y aplica el cambio y contraste predefinido por el navegador.
Comparto un ejemplo del uso que estoy haciendo de las media queries mencionadas:


div {background-color: purple;}
.cssColor th,td {color: black; height: 100px; background-color:blue; width: 150px; text-align:center;border: 2px dashed orange;}
 .cssColor h1 {color: green}
 .cssColor a {color: red}
 
 @media (prefers-color-scheme: light){
    .cssColor th.thlight,td.tdlight {color: purple; background-color: yellow; font-weight:bold; border: 2px dashed red;}
    .cssColor h1.h1light {color: orange;}
    .cssColor a.alight {color: green}
 }
 
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
div {background-color: blue;}
    .cssColor th.thdark,td.tddark {color: white; background-color: orange; font-weight:bold; border: 2px dashed red;}
    .cssColor h1.h1dark {color: red;}
    .cssColor a.adark {color: blue}
 }
<html>
<body>
<div>
<table class="cssColor">
<thead>
<tr><th class="thlight thdark><h1  class="h1light h1dark">Title</h1></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="tdlight tddark">Body 1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="tdlight tddark"><a hre="#" class="alight adark">Body Link</a></td></tr>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>



Necesitaría encontrar un modo viable de controlar los cambios necesarios en los emails para ambos sistemas operativos mediante CSS.
De antemano, muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda.

Te recomiendo agregar un [MCVE] corto y claro, un div con un color de fondo basta y sobra para tu caso. Por otro lado, no creo que exista una respuesta única para los correos; los clientes de correo suelen modificar estilos a conveniencia, además que el motor de renderización para los clientes de escritorios suele ser incompleto, motivo por el cual se utilizan técnicas de la década de los 90' como usar tablas para maquetar

Hola, no entiendo lo de color del fondo, lo incluyo si quieres, pero los elementos del código que he compartido ya lo tiene css funcional y verificable en un email de prueba. Es precisamente que por este problema de renderización que no he incluido ningún div y tengo que maquetar emails con tablas y de milagro no tengo que hacerlo con piedra y cincel XD.

Ya he incluido el div con color de fondo. Gracias por tu ayuda @Yussef

Después de muchas pruebas e investigaciones sobre como solventar el problema de la visualización en dark-mode para los gestores de correo más habituales y con sistemas operativos Android he podido hallar respuesta aplicando los siguientes parámetros:

Inclusión en el head del html de email de etiquetas meta que permitan la
identificación del gestor de correo compatible.
Utilización de prefijos de tipo [data-ogsc] y [data-ogsb] para
incluir estilos en las etiquetas de bloqueo de correo electrónico.

El código para este email de prueba quedaría del siguiente modo:


div {background-color: purple;}
.cssColor th,td {color: black; height: 100px; background-color:blue; width: 150px; text-align:center;border: 2px dashed orange;}
 .cssColor h1 {color: green}
 .cssColor a {color: red}
 
 @media (prefers-color-scheme: light){
    .cssColor th.thlight,td.tdlight {color: purple; background-color: yellow; font-weight:bold; border: 2px dashed red;}
    .cssColor h1.h1light {color: orange;}
    .cssColor a.alight {color: green}
 }
 
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
div {background-color: blue;}
    .cssColor th.thdark,td.tddark {color: white; background-color: orange; font-weight:bold; border: 2px dashed red;}
    .cssColor h1.h1dark {color: red;}
    .cssColor a.adark {color: blue}
 }
<html>
<head>

<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">

<style>
[data-ogsc] div {
    background-color: #838383;
    color: #FFF5EE;
}

[data-ogsb] div {
    background-color: #838383;
    color: #FFF5EE;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<table class="cssColor">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="thlight thdark">
      <h1 class="h1light h1dark">Title</h1>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdlight tddark">Body 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdlight tddark">
        <a hre="#" class="alight adark">Body Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>



Resulta de notable importancia comprobar la compatibilidad, tanto por dispositivo, como por gestor de correo, con estos métodos de implementación del modo dark-mode en nuestras campañas de mailing.
